# .NET 4.0 Graphics library - How can I capture the "whole" screen?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I'm coding a small app to take a screenshot every X seconds and I've ran into a small but annoying roadblock. Take this image, for example:

Screen captured using the default 'Print Screen' function on Windows 7
[image]

If I try to take the same screenshot by using the default .NET 4 Graphics library, the circled area doesn't show up. Same happens with Visual Studio tabbed menus and some other apps I can't remember. The rest of the image comes out fine, tho.

This is the code I'm using. I might be screwing something up but I can't figure it for the life of me. Any help would be appreciated:

```
memoryImage = new Bitmap(resolution.Width, resolution.Height);
Size s = new Size(memoryImage.Width, memoryImage.Height);
// Create graphics 
Console.WriteLine("Creating Graphics...");
Console.WriteLine();
Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);

// Copy data from screen 
Console.WriteLine("Copying data from screen...");
Console.WriteLine();
memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, s);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This test saves correctly the whole screen on my configuration (Windows 10, VS 2015) =>

```
Rectangle screenBounds = Screen.GetBounds(System.Drawing.Point.Empty);
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(screenBounds.Width, screenBounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {                       
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    }
    bitmap.Save("e:\\ScreenCopy.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```